# Gradle: Error listing versions of junit#junit;4.+

Tags: junit, proxy, gradle, dependency-management

I am getting the below error when running `gradle build` on my gradle.properties file.

I know I am behind a firewall and I have a poxy I can use. I've tried adding the below to my gradle.properties file, but I cannot pull down jUnit. All help appreciated!

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
```

Error:

```
Error listing versions of junit#junit;4.+ using class 
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenVersionLister$1. 
Will attempt an alternate way to list versions. This behaviour has been 
deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testRuntime'.
> Could not resolve junit:junit:4.+.
  Required by:
      :HealthMonitor:1.0
   > Failed to list versions for junit#junit;4.+.
      > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]'.
         > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/'.
            > Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Health Monitor', 'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the proxy, you may have to configure more than just the host and port. See [Accessing the web via a proxy](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec%3aaccessing_the_web_via_a_proxy) in the Gradle User Guide. Also, I recommend to try with a fixed version rather than a version range.